# Thymeleaf and JPA - object saving isn't possible

Tags: spring, jpa, thymeleaf

I have a problem with setting my Country object to my Pet object.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

My Pet class

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Pet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Country country;
    }
```

I've tried to do this in this way(countries is list of all countries from database, I added this to model as a attribute):

```
    <form th:object = "${pet}" th:action="@{/pet/}" method = "post">
    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{country}" >
        <option th:each="countryVal : ${countries}"
                th:value="${countryVal}"
                th:text="${countryVal.getName()}"
                >val
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

But this don't save country object to my Pet object. 
I had to do this in this way, I save only id to country object:

```
<form th:object = "${pet}" th:action="@{/pet/}" method = "post">
    <select class="form-control" th:name="country.id" >
        <option th:each="countryVal : ${countries}"
                th:value="${countryVal.id}"
                th:text="${countryVal.getName()}"
                >val
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Is there some way to save my country object from list to country in Pet object?
Or some another way.
Is this code with country.id proper way to save existed object from database to object in my Pet class?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `th:field` in `select` tag. Try this

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{country}"> // * is NOTa typo here
    <option th:each="countryVal : ${countries}"
            th:value="${countryVal.id}"
            th:text="${countryVal.getName()}"
            >val
    </option>
</select>
```

Disclaimer: This applies to Thymeleaf 3.

Comment: Country is still null. In your way.
I tried to use country in controller after submit and i got java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: I have no clues what are you talking about, but it should be done like I have showed you. `th:field` is mandatory here. You better check where do you get NPE

Comment: When I do this in your way, there in database is null field for column country_id in pet table.

Comment: The something is wrong with your `countries` This is how it should be done.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you.